# Yii2 Throwing UserException includes the stack trace to the end user

Tags: php, exception, yii2

Suddenly my Yii2 site Throwing UserException started showing stack trace to the end-user.

here is the my code:

```
$errorMessage = "This is error";
throw new \yii\base\UserException($errorMessage);
```

[image]

nothing is changed in that code and not sure what's changed in Yii core or something.

**Yii2 updated**

```
yiisoft/yii2 (2.0.39.3 => 2.0.40)
```

Please help

Comment: First of all switch to production mode so it won't show stack to the users. Second - there is almost no information here, how can we help you? Have you updated Yii? If yes, from which version to which? If not, how can there be changes in the core? Most probable explanation is that the environment has changed, database, data files, system, etc.

Comment: Wow you throw some exception.. but what is the code? Give more information...

Comment: @Bizley added information in question

Comment: Ok, so this looks like an exception made by you, right? Where do you throw it? You are playing hard to get ;)

Comment: This looks like the exception is being caught and dumped somewhere instead of letting it get to Yii's error handler.